Help with format of Altium Spice model
I am attempting to create a model of a load for use in an Altium Spice model. But I am unable to get it to work. What I have done is accurately measure current consumption of my device. My concept was to model the load with a resistance that changes over time in order to illicit the measured current from the power supply circuit. Two questions:

Could you identify the error in the model syntax:
* SPICE library for multiple operating modes
.subckt mode1 Vcc GND
Rload Vcc GND R=V(Vcc)/I(t)
.param I(t) = PWL(
  0.050 48529409
  0.051 51562498
  0.052 62264148
  0.053 58928569
  0.054 63461536
  0.055 59999998
)
.ends mode1



When I use this model, Altium does not recognise the format:


My goal is to produce a number of current profiles and simulate them one after another. Any idea how this would be possible? I.e. one mode would be WiFi connect. The next would be BLE open session... Ideally, it would be possible to select the mode in the Altium simulation, or even script to run them one after the other???

Update
Following up on @SteKulov 's solution. I wonder if there is a compatibility issue in Altium's understand of the model grammar?



Hmmm…you got a lot of weird SPICE syntax here. Did you just make a bunch of guesses on what would be accepted? It sounds like you just need a G-source (SPICE lingo for voltage controlled current source) for what you want to do.

Actually, I might’ve misread your attempt at the .subckt. You might just need a PWL current source which is even easier.

If you confirm that my answer does what you want for the 1st question, then I can probably address the 2nd question for you too.

@SteKulov Yes! That does provide a working solution. Great simplification! Apologies for the syntax. Problem is I'm pulling example code from all over the place, and I am clearly drawing from several incompatible syntaxes. Original goal was to simulate in Altium, but Altium does not recognise TI device models! But if I simulate in TI, I'll have to somehow extract PCB parasitics and transmission lines etc into TI. It's a bit of a nightmare how un-unified these simulation tools seems to be.

OK.  Can you clarify the 2nd question then.  When you say run one after another, assuming they're all 0.1s long, do you mean from 0.0s to 0.1s you do one profile then from 0.1s to 0.2s you do the next and 0.2 to 0.3s the next etc.?  Or is it okay for them to all be plotted from 0.0s 0.1s and they show up in different colors on the plot?  As for the TI models, can you list which ones you have problems with importing?

Sure! For example, TPS61291. I can import it and add it to the component, but when you run it, the outputs don't make any sense. It won't let you feed 3V to the input. And when you do find an input voltage it accepts, it appears to only operate in bypass mode! Clearly TI's models include code that is not being understood.

In terms of running one after another, my intention was to create individual loading profiles and be able to simulate them in isolation. For example, where I use a WiFi & BT enabled MCU - and want to run each of these operating modes one after the other. I could just append the models with a short pause I suppose!


Could you identify the error in the model syntax:

You need to use + symbol for continuation (of your .param command):
* SPICE library for multiple operating modes
.subckt mode1 Vcc GND
Rload Vcc GND R=V(Vcc)/I(t)
.param I(t) = PWL(
+  0.050 48529409
+  0.051 51562498
+  0.052 62264148
+  0.053 58928569
+  0.054 63461536
+  0.055 59999998
+)
.ends mode1

For your 2nd question I have no answer. :-(

A bunch of your SPICE syntax makes no sense (MarianD's answer already pointed one out), but it doesn't matter since I think you might be overthinking how to do this.  It sounds like you just need a PWL current source as your load.  I don't have Altium (costs $$$), but this is how I would do this in LTspice (costs $0).


If you have a lot of PWL points, you can put them in a "PWL file" like this to reduce clutter:


If Altium doesn't have the PWL file feature, then making a subcircuit encapsulating the current source is a reasonable alternative.  Then you can also make the symbol whatever you want as long as it has a SPICE prefix of X, which Altium probably does for you automatically when you select Model Type as "SPICE Subcircuit".

To reduce clutter further, you can put the subcircuit into an external file and .lib or .inc it.  Your Altium screenshot seems to do this for you already in that "Model Description" section.

You mentioned in the comments that your goal is to simulate how a DC-DC converter reacts to such a load.  This type of non-ideal source can drop its voltage close to zero if the load current is high enough.  Using an ideal current source as a load, like above, would then generate power back to the source.  LTspice has a built-in mechanism for this kind of problem, which is flagging your current source as a load.  The help file explains it like this:

This circuit element sources a constant current between nodes n+ and
n-. If the source is flagged as a load, the source is forced to be
dissipative, that is, the current goes to zero if the voltage between
nodes n+ and n- goes to zero. The purpose of this option is to model a
current load on a power supply that doesn't draw current if the output
voltage is zero. When flagged as a load, the current source starts to
deviate from a constant current when the voltage across it drops to
0.5V. The impedance eventually drops to a resistance equal to .25Ω/amp times the value of the current source.

However, not all simulators have this feature.  Therefore, another way around this is what you were trying to do initially, but it's not that straightforward and can be a little tricky.  You measured the current consumption profile when under an ideal voltage source, and you want to calculate a resistance based on these numbers.  Then you want to apply this resistance to your non-ideal voltage source (DC-DC converter output) and see how it fares.  You can't generate a PWL() resistance directly, but you can start with a PWL current source (or voltage source if you want) and convert it to a resistance.  Here is one way to do such a thing, which should be compatible across all SPICE3-based simulators.

The trick here is that you can create a resistance out of a behavioral current source where the syntax for the source would be I=V(load)/R.  You can generate an independent PWL current source off to the side and then you can use your intended ideal Vcc divided by this PWL current source as the R in that equation.  Notice how the non-ideality added by R2 affects the current through the actual load I(B1).  If this resistor wasn't here, the plots would match because then the voltage at the load would match the Vcc we used in the "resistor" equation.  Of course, all this looks neater when packaged within a .subckt.


Hey. I've thought a bit more about this. I can see that in theory this should work - if the currents are kept realistic. But in a DC-DC boost circuit, the output voltage depends on the interaction between the load and the circuit’s ability to supply power. If you replace a varying load with a current source, especially one demanding an unphysically high current, it could result in the circuit entering an impossible state. I assume there is no such thing as a piecewise resistive load? That would be a more robust model element.

@monkey I don't know about Altium, but in LTspice this is solved by flagging the current source as a load.  What this does is automatically switches the current source to a resistor when the voltage drops to near zero, eliminating the impossible state (or with an ideal current source preventing it from sourcing current back to the power supply circuit).  I'm trying to think of an easy method of how to do this in a simulator that may not have that feature.

Actually, I believe LTspice models are supported by Altium! What started out as a quick "I'll just run a few sims on a spice model to see how it performs" could turn into a full blown project.

@monkey  I couldn't find any info on the Altium docs where load is supported, so I posted a method (based on your initial intent) that should work on any SPICE simulator.

I've run that through Altium. It's still complaining, but at this point, I have no doubt that your solution is correct. Is it a limitation in Altium's spice compiler or something, that it isn't able to interpret the model as LTspice clearly has for you?

@monkey  Try including curly braces around the I= expression, so it's this: I={V(plus,minus)/(Vload/I(R1))}.  That's my bad, they should be there for universal compatibility (even though LTspice yells at me that they're redundant, haha).
